# cобытия для собственного шаблона Placemark

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

такая проблема у меня есть несколько меток на карте и можно выбрать только одну активную, которую я сохраняю в переменную activePlacemark. При клике на эту же точку она деактивируется (удаляется класс active), также меняется активная точка при клике на другую.

Метод build и clear отрабатывает несколько раз, хотя я хотел бы чтобы метод clear отрабатывал только при удалении элемента, а не изменении свойства. Можно ли так?

Условно при сворачивании в кластер удаляются листнеры, а при отображении вновь навешиваются. Но все эти действия происходят при изменении свойств

Вот так выглядит шаблон в котором проставляется проставляется класс в зависимости от свойства

```
 `<div class="placemark {% if properties.isActive %}active{% endif %}">
          ${this.getItemIcon(item)}
          <svg class="mark" width="52" height="52" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 73"><path d="M32.2 8.39A19.72 19.72 0 0 0 12.46 28.1c0 5.5 2.3 10.37 7.36 15.53L32.2 56l12.36-12.36c5.07-5.17 7.36-10.03 7.36-15.53A19.73 19.73 0 0 0 32.2 8.4z"/></svg>
         </div>`
```

Методы шаблона

```
build: {
    if (self.activePlacemark) {
       self.activePlacemark
       .getData()
       .properties.unset('isActive');
}
  self.activePlacemark = this;
  this.getData().properties.set('isActive', true);
}
clear: function() {
     // когда точка удаляется мы удаляем все обработчики
     // необходимо удалять обработчик
     console.log('удаляем обработчик', this);
     this.getData().geoObject.events.remove(
          'mousedown',
          this.placemarkHandler,
          this,
     );

     lay.superclass.clear.call(this);
 },
```

Пример взял с песочницы

https://jsfiddle.net/nz16wygh/

Answer (score 2):

Переопределите метод [`rebuild`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/layout.templateBased.Base-docpage/#method_detail__rebuild), он отвечает за обновление макета при изменении данных или опций. По-умолчанию он делает `this.clear();this.build();`.